# Fastai learner not loading

Tags: machine-learning, model, pytorch, resnet, fast-ai

So I'm trying to load a model using:

```
learn = create_cnn(data, models.resnet50, lin_ftrs=[2048], metrics=accuracy) 
learn.clip_grad();
learn.load(f'{name}-stage-2.1')
```

But I get the following error

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Sequential:
size mismatch for 1.8.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([5004, 2048]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([4542, 2048]).
size mismatch for 1.8.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([5004]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([4542]).
```

The only thing that is different thing is that I added a random validation split that wasn't there in the `stage-2.1` model, when I remove the split and have no validation set as the `stage-2.1` was trained all goes well.

Whats happening?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`cnn_learner`](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.learner.html#cnn_learner) method and latest [`Pytorch`](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) with latest [`FastAI`](https://docs.fast.ai/install.html). There was a [`breaking change`](https://forums.fast.ai/t/create-cnn-metric-error/40059/2) and discontinuity so you suffer now.

The fastai website has many examples such as [`this one`](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/master/examples/dogs_cats.ipynb).

```
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=accuracy)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your torch.Size([5004, 2048]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([4542, 2048])
you have to change it.